# Let $A$ be positive definite and $A^{-1}=A^*$ then $A=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in{M_n}$ be positive definite and $A^{-1}=A^*$.

Can we prove that $A=I$?

Comment: Do you use $A^*$ to denote the Hermitian adjoint, or conjugate transpose of $A$, which is often denoted by $A^\dagger$?  Cheers!

Comment: $A^*$=conjugate transpose of A

Comment: Thanks for thecr rapid clarification!

Comment: @Robert Lewis -Ok

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can.

**Hint:** If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $A^*A = I$, then show that $|\lambda| = 1$.

Comment: @  Omnomnomnom  -Thanks and Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$A^{-1}$=$A^*$ $\Rightarrow$ $I=AA^*$ $\Rightarrow$ $|t|$=$1$,

where $t$ denotes the eigenvalue of $A$. Since, $t \gt 0$, $t$ can only be 1.